# Can an article include "A Comparative Study" in its title if its main purpose is not comparison?

Tags: publications, journals, peer-review

If the main purpose of an article is to present/introduce a new method, can it still be entitled "A Comparative Study"? Or does it depend on how much of the article is devoted to the comparison of related methods? I am asking from the perspective of a reviewer.

Comment: You can call the article whatever you want.  But why would you want to use a name that only refers to a minor part of the work?

Comment: Thanks. I am actually reviewing such an article. I found it odd but I was not sure if it is "wrong".

Comment: I would not introduce a false dichotomy of "right"/"wrong". A scale from "bad" to "excellent" should be used. As a reviewer I'd ask the authors to improve the title and might even recommend an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not introduce a false dichotomy of "right"/"wrong". A scale from "bad" to "excellent" should be used. However, a misleading title is generally not acceptable.

As a reviewer I'd ask the authors to improve the title and might even recommend an alternative. This happens fairly regularly. Some reviewer guidelines explicitly ask the reviewer to check if the title is appropriate and some review forms have a subitem where you are asked to indicate if the title is appropriate.

Finding the perfect title can be surprisingly hard and an outside perspective from a reviewer can sometimes be very valuable to improve it. Most authors are receptive to suggestions concerning the title.

An interesting example is ["Replicate or lie" (Prosser, 2010)](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1462-2920.2010.02201.x/full) which even acknowledges a reviewer for the catchy title:

> I am very grateful for the invaluable comments of both reviewers of
>   this article, one of whom is solely responsible for the title.

Answer (score 6):

In many ways, the title of a scientific work can be thought of as a super-short abstract. In other words, it should tersely summarize what a reader is likely to find most salient in that work.

Thus, if you are a reviewer encountering a title that you find misleading as relates to the content, then it is entirely reasonable and appropriate to suggest that the title be changed.  As flaws in a paper go, however, I would find it pretty minor from a reviewing standpoint, since it doesn't much affect the content and is very easy to fix.